# How to write query results in impala to a CSV file with JDBC Driver

Tags: impala

Using Impala JDBC driver, is it possible to write query results to a CSV file?

OR is impala-shell the only way to achieve this?

What are the security/performance side-effects of calling impala-shell from a web application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Impala's SQL syntax currently supports this feature. I've [filed an issue](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-2073) to request it.